# Convert SQL to LINQ, with multiple joins and a predicate

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, join

I am struggling with trying to write a LINQ statement in LINQ or method syntax, based on the following SQL.

```
SELECT vr.* 
FROM VisualReport vr
JOIN VisualReportRoleList vrl ON vr.VisualReportSK = vrl.VisualReportSK
JOIN Role r ON vrl.RoleSK = r.RoleID
JOIN UserRoleList url ON r.RoleID = url.RoleID
JOIN Users u ON url.UserID = url.UserID
WHERE u.ID = 1
```

I have tried many things, but without luck. I was going to post some of it here, but it just made this post really messy to read.

Can anyone here help me with this?

Comment: there are some pretty good tools out there that can help you do this.. do a google search on `LinqPad` see if there is a free donwload trial version

Answer (score 0):

Join pattern works like this

Param 1. is the list to join on,

Param 2. key on the left (what your calling join on),

Param 3. key on the right (what your joining to),

Param 4. is the results selector how you want to select the results.

```
db.VisualReposts.Join(db.VisualRepostRoleLists, 
                      vr => vr.VisualReportSK,
                      vrl => vrl.VisualReportSK 
                      (vr, vrl) => new { vr, vrl}).Join(db.Roles, 
                                                       vrj => vrj.vrl.RoleSK,
                                                       r => r.RoleID,
                                                  vrj, r => new {vr = vrj.vr, 
                                                                vrl = vrj.vrl, 
                                                                role = r} )

  //follow the same patter for the rest of the joins.  
  // Also add your where clause, it might be a better idea to start 
  //from the users table so you can filter first
```

But if everything is properly foreign keyed, you don't need to do a join you can just access the ICollections. If you can or have them foreign keyed you can access them like this

```
var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.id == 1);

//everything should have an icollection now so you can access via
//user.UserRoleList.Roles ect or what ever you need
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one to one conversion. LinqPad should convert this to equivalent of your query.

```
var result = (from vr in VisualReport
    join vrl in VisualReportRoleList on vr.VisualReportSK equals vrl.VisualReportSK
    join r in Role on vrl.RoleSK equals r.RoleID
    join url in UserRoleList on vrl.RoleSK equals url.RoleID
    join u in Users on url.UserID equals u.UserID
    where u.ID == 1
    select vr).ToList();
```